# Асинхронный итератор

Tags: python, python-3.x, async-await, асинхронность

У меня есть итератор, который получает прокси из другого сервиса.

```
class StaticProxyIterator:
    def __init__(self, pa_client):
        self.pa_client = pa_client

    def __aiter__(self):
        return self

    async def __anext__(self):
        m = proxy_agent.GetProxies()
        resp, status = await self.pa_client.request(m)
        check_status(status, 200)
        empty_response(resp)
        for p in resp:
            yield p
```

Этот итератор я хочу вызывать так, в рамках асинхронной функции:

```
async def execute():
    invalid_statuses = []
    content = None
    async for p in self.__proxy_it:
        print(p)
```

Но я получаю это:

> TypeError: 'async for' received an invalid object from **anext**:
>   async_generator

В чём причина и как побороть? В ходе экспериментов, я выяснил, что проблема в наличии самого итератора, т.е. в слове `yield`. Если его убрать, то всё работает.

Comment: Как и `__next__` в синхронных итераторах, `__anext__` обязан возвращать строго один объект без всяких yield

Comment: @andreymal окей, если мне нужно проитерироваться по коллекции, как мне тогда это сделать с сохранением состояния в переменной класса?

Comment: Всё, я дурачок-чок-чок. Увидел бред...

Comment: `self._состояние = объект_состояния` ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: А вообще конкретно этот пример прекрасно записывается одной функцией `async def static_proxies(pa_client)` с `yield` внутри без всяких классов